# Complex number question with a constant

Tags: complex-numbers

For which real values of α does the following equation have non-zero solutions?
z + z* = α|z| .
Sketch the set of those solutions for any such value of α.

I gained values of 2 and -2 for α, but realise I am unable to sketch this in the complex plane.

Comment: You can also get $\alpha = 0$, as in $i+\overline i=0$.  Or $\alpha = 1$, via $z= 1+\sqrt 3 i$, and so on.

Comment: Do you mean $$x+iy+x-iy=\alpha\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

Comment: Exactly this form

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=x+iy$ and rewrite the equation,

$$2x=a\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

$$4x^2= a^2 (x^2+y^2)$$

$$(4-a^2)x^2=a^2y^2$$

$$\sqrt{4-a^2}x=\pm ay$$

Thus, for $-2\le a \le 2$, there are non-zero solutions, which are in general two lines through origin in the complex plane for a given $a$.

Note that, for $0<a<2$, $x>0$ from $2x=a|z|$.  So, the lines in the 1st and 2nd quadrants are the valid solutions. For $-2<a<0$, the lines are in the 3rd and 4th quadrants. The solutions degenerate to one line if $ a=0, \pm 2$.

Comment: Thank you. Would substituting in alpha = 2 and -2 not both just give the line y=x however? i am confused on how to map this onto a complex plane

Comment: As square root of (4-α^2) gives (2 - α) and (2 + α). I am not sure how to plot this on the complex plane

Comment: Note that the square root of (4-a^2) is $\pm\sqrt{4-a^2}$

Comment: Sorry, I'm not making myself clear. Substituting in the bounds for a as 2 and -2, gives the same result of sqrt(4-a^2) which is zero.

Comment: Strictly speaking, last line should be $\sqrt{4-a^2} x  = \pm |a y|$.

Comment: In the case of $a=\pm 2$, the two solutions degenerate to one $y=0$, which is the x-axis.

Comment: So how would I sketch this, as from this I am just going to get a line on y=0. Is this the solution all other values?

Comment: Yes. $y=0$ is a valid solution.

Comment: More specifically, the possible x-axis is the solution for a = 2 and the negative x-axis is the solution for a = -2.

Answer (score 0):

As you observed in the comments, if $z + z^* = \alpha\lvert z\rvert$
where $z=x+iy$ then

$$2x=a\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.\tag1$$

Notice that $x = y = 0$ is a solution regardless of the value of $\alpha.$
But if we consider the case where $x$ and $y$ are not both zero,
Equation $(1)$ says that $x$ must have the same sign as $\alpha.$
That is, if $\alpha$ is positive $x$ then must be positive,
if $\alpha$ is negative then $x$ must be negative,
and if $\alpha = 0$ then $x = 0.$

Solving for $y$ in Equation $(1)$ in the case where $\alpha \neq 0$,

$$ y = \pm \left( \frac{\sqrt{4 - a^2}}{a} \right) x. \tag2$$

(Almost all the details of this solution are already worked out in another answer, so I will not repeat them.)

Equation $(2)$ gives you equations of two lines, but remember that we still have the constraint that $x$ must have the same sign as $\alpha$ (unless $x = y = 0$).
So you get only a part of each of the lines.

Try sketching the solution set for $\alpha = \sqrt2.$
Then try  $\alpha = -\sqrt2.$
Can you generalize?